# I can't link CSS file to HTML file in Django project

Tags: python, html, css, django

HTML file is working well. But it's not linking with CSS, what I make in CSS simply does not work.

## HTML PAGE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>TheWebPub</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylepage.css">
</head>
<body>
    {% if name %}
    <h1 class='title'>Hello {{name}}. </h1>
    {% else %}
    <h1>Hello world.</h1>
    {% endif %}

    <p>Thank you for being here in my website, it's my first one. I'm creating this website with django/python.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

everything seems to be ok. it's my views.py file in my django project

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import request

# Create your views here.

def say_hello(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'name':'Adryan'})
```

Comment: Where did you store the css file? Can you share the filetree?

Comment: it's in templates folder, together with my html file. In the usual way

Comment: well that is not the usual way, since the browser can not read from the template. You typically store this in the `static/` directory and let the nginx server serve these files.

Answer (score 4):

You can not pass a reference to a file in the `templates` directory, indeed a browser has no access to this: the templates are opened by the webserver, and then rendered and the result is often then passed as response, as is here the case.

What you do to work with static (or media) files is store these in the `static/` root that is at the same level as the `manage.py` file. In `DEBUG = True` mode, you can Django serve static (and media) files by adding these to the *root* `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # the rest of your URLconf goes here …
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

in the template we then pass a reference to this file:

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'stylepage.css' %}">
```

In production, you will have to configure the webserver, like nginx or apache to serve static files.

For more information, see the [*How to manage static files* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/static-files/).

Comment: I just would like to know which of the 2 urls.py I need to code this, there is one with settings and other inside of my app folder

Comment: in the *root* `urls.py`, so (likely) not the one in the app folders.